# How to invoke a UDF with LINQ in Cosmos DB SDK v3?

Tags: linq, azure-cosmosdb

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-linq-to-sql) for LINQ to SQL translation for Cosmos DB states:

> User-Defined Function Extension function: Supports translation from the stub method UserDefinedFunctionProvider.Invoke to the corresponding user-defined function.

However, this function is not publicly accessible in .NET SDK v3 (though it is in v2). So what's the workaround until the bug has been fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several workarounds:

1. Don't use LINQ.
2. Use LINQ but without calling UDFs, then get the query string using `query.ToQueryDefinition.QueryText` and manipulate it to insert UDF calls at the places you need them, and then evaluate the SQL string (yuck!).
3. Hack it. First add a dummy method:

```
    public static object Invoke(string udfName, object[] arguments) { return null; }
```

Use this method in your lambda expressions whenever you would otherwise use `UserDefinedFunctionProvider.Invoke`. Implement an `ExpressionVisitor` that replaces all occurrences of `MethodCallExpression mce` where `mce.Method` matches the dummy method by

```
Expression.Call(null, udfMethod, mce.Arguments[0], mce.Arguments[1])
```

where `udfMethod` is

```
MethodInfo udfMethod = typeof(CosmosClient).Assembly
                .GetType("Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq.UserDefinedFunctionProvider", throwOnError: true)
                .GetMethod("Invoke", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
```

Use the resulting expression in your `Where`, `Select` etc.

(Add a unit test to check when the bug has been fixed and the hack can be removed.)

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos 3.22.1 SDK for my example with the UDF (user defined functions) and it worked fine.

I used the [example from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.linq.cosmoslinq.invokeuserdefinedfunction?view=azure-dotnet&preserve-view=true#examples).

It is of course also possible to use the UDF in combination with where clauses.

```
CosmosClient client = new(endpoint, key);

IQueryable<Product> queryable = client
    .GetContainer("database", "products")
    .GetItemLinqQueryable<Product>()
    .Select(b => new Product{ id = b.id, price = b.price, priceWithTax = CosmosLinq.InvokeUserDefinedFunction("tax", b.price).ToString() });

var productIterator = queryable.ToFeedIterator<Product>();
while (productIterator.HasMoreResults)
{
    var responseMessage = await productIterator.ReadNextAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseMessage));
}
```